# Wireless LAN not working on Lenovo Ideapad S205

Tags: wireless, 12.04, connection, lenovo, ideapad

I can't get the Wireless connection on my Ideapad S205 to work. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. The network manager indicates that Wireless was disabled by hardware switch, which isn't true.

I checked out various guides but none of them helped me, Most likely because of the fact that they were written for 11.04 or 11.10.

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

deep in a bug report I found a solution that worked for me. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...ux/+bug/875659

"At least for the IdeaPad S205 model 1038 there is a quite weird workaround:

After installation there is a mysterious "ubuntu" entry in the boot order that must not be at the top. So go to your "BIOS" with F2 and change the boot order so the hardisk comes before "ubuntu" entry. Seems like a buggy EFI/BIOS implementation.

Kudos goes to the german guys at http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-karte-ralink-rt3090-lenovo-ideapad-s205-l/"

Comment: Weird, but it works. Thanks a lot!